# How to check if a facebook account has enabled 2FA?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am building an app with social login. One of the requirement for the local created accounts is that the user is forced to use 2FA.

Using Facebook's api with a valid client app how do I check if the user who just signed up is not reckless and use 2FA ? (Wondering the same thing with google too).

Comment: I don’t think that info is exposed via API at all. Give the “bad guys” an easy way to figure out which accounts are less secure? That would probably not be a good idea.

Comment: @04FS you're right... lol never saw that that way. But I heard google is offering that feature. The user is giving your app permission to read their account infos and you have the flag there.